# iOS NSString in UTF16

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurlconnection, utf-16

I have a string that I fetched from an Apache server over HTTP:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    ...
```

I need to make that string a UTF16 string.  I don't want to turn it into NSData.  I need to keep it NSString and I need it to be in UTF16.
I would be happy to put it in an NSData object even, if I could do it as UTF16.  I'm doing something similar now:

```
[self.returnedData appendData:data];
```

But that still transfers it as UTF8.
It's probably simple and I'm missing it.  But I don't find it in the Apple docs or this site, and my Google-Fu has failed me.
What am I missing?  How do I do that?
Thanks for your time and help.

EDIT:
Ok.  All of what you and Justin have said makes sense and makes things make more sense.
So this is what I am doing.  It seems to be correct from this line but I wanted to make sure I am understanding you correctly.

```
NSData *resultData = [self. result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSString *resultStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSString *md5Result = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultStr MD5]] uppercaseString];
NSLog(@"md5Result = %@",md5Result);
```

That last part is what I am doing with the string after it's UTF-16.  I have a category that makes it an MD5 hex string similar to http://blog.blackwhale.at/?tag=hmac
Thanks again.  I'll bump you guys both and say this is the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string is a string is a string. The encoding refers to how its encoded and decoded to and from NSData. @"blah" is the same as @"blah". There is no UTF8 or UTF 16 for either of those.

**Added**
So you can do `[@"myString" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];`

If you convert that back to a string, you'll still have @"myString"

**Answer** last question in comment below.
So when you POST to a server the server body is encoded data. So what you wanted to do is do what ever you want to the string. THEN convert the string to data using a particular encoding, in your case, NSUTF16StringEncoding or NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding. You are NOT creating UTF-16 string. You are converting a unicode string to UTF-16 encoded data. This is what you need to do then.

`NSData *postBody = [[[self.result MD5] uppercaseString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];`

If you need to add more data to the postBody create NSMutableData instead and append the new data as needed.

Comment: Hrm.  Clearly there is something I don't understand.  But I was reading in the NSString Docs that they are natively UTF8.  If I change the line: responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; to responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; it does not print correctly.  So there must be something to the encoding.  I have also been told that Apache sends strings as UTF8.  What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: If your data is encoded using UTF8, then you have to use NSUTF8StringEncoding. If it's encoded UTF16, then you have to use NSUTF16StringEncoding. It depends on how the data is encoded.

Comment: It is, in fact, encoded with UTF-8.  So how does one convert it to a string that has UTF-16 encoding?  Something similar to Java's string.getBytes(UTF16)?

Comment: The equivalent of `string.getBytes(UTF16)` is `[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];`  getBytes returns an array of Bytes, not an array of char nor a new String object

Comment: Also NSString is not"encoded" it is an array of Unicode characters. UTF-8 or UTF-16 indicate how those characters are represented in binary format.

Comment: Ok.  All of what you and Justin makes sense and makes things make more sense.
So this is what I am doing.  It seems to be correct from this line but I wanted to make sure I am understanding you correctly.              
NSData *resultData = [self. result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    NSString *resultStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    NSString *md5Result = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultStr MD5]] uppercaseString];
    NSLog(@"resultPin = %@",resultPin);

Comment: What are you doing with md5result? Posting it to a server that require UTF-16?

Comment: It gets encrypted some more and then sent to the server.  They are requiring UTF-16.

Comment: See my appended answer above.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` holds a buffer of whatever encoding it chooses - that may be UTF-8, UTF-16, or something else.

If you just want to create an `NSString` from a UTF-16 sequence, try `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding` or one of its relatives.

Comment: TO the best of my knowledge there is not a way to directly convert an NSString to UTF-16 using NSUTF16StringEncoding without putting it in an NSData object.  Is that not Correct?  For instance this does not work: responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];  It prints out as Kanji or something.

Comment: you should specify the endianness for data received over the wire. try "`NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding` or one of its relatives".

Comment: but it's not even entirely clear if you are trying to convert a utf16 string to NSString, or the other way around.

Comment: Good point!  I am getting a message form Apache so it is UTF-8 by default (confirmed by the keepers of the server).  I then need to change it to a UTF-16 string to encrypt in a process not under my control.

Comment: ok - in that case, just use dbrajkovic's suggestion but be encoding aware, like so: `[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];` (note that you may need little endian instead of big).